# How to filtering out json object contain certain key in FLASK?

Tags: python

I have a JSON file :

```
    {
           "id":"xyz",
           "word":"this is word",
           "formats":[
              {
                 "formatId":"xz99",
                 "pengeluaran":"pengeluaran_1",
                 
              },
              {
                 "formatId":"xy100",
                 "pengeluaran":"pengeluaran_2",
                 
              },
              {
                 
                 "ukuran":451563,
                 "formatId":"xy101",
                 "pengeluaran":"pengeluaran_1",
             
            },
        }
```

in my python.py files, i want to filtering out the JSON object only contain "ukuran" as a key , my expected to getting result like this :

```
    {
           "id":"xyz",
           "word":"this is word",
           "formats":[
              {
                 
                 "ukuran":451563,
                 "formatId":"xy101",
                 "pengeluaran":"pengeluaran_1",
             
            },
        }
```

this my python.py code :

```
    def extractJson(appData):    
        appData = json.loads(output)
        
        //list comprehension to filter out only JSON object contain "ukuran"?

        print(appData)
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It could look something like this:

This example uses list comprehension to filter out the correct format by checking to see if the format contains the key `"ukuran"`, and then assigning the filtered list back `"formats"` key for the object.

```
def extractJson(output):    
    appData = json.loads(output)
    appData["formats"] = [
       format for format in appData["formats"] if "ukuran" in format
    ]
    print(appData)
    return appData
```